# Society/culture of intelligent, eusocial ambush predator aliens?

Tags: society, aliens, culture

EDIT:// Mainly looking for religion/politics I suppose, but any answer would be great. Not omnivorous at all, I thought I made that clear already. Local ecology/environment -- I already described where they live, or do you mean something else? Sons tend to stay with the birth-family while daughters marry unrelated males and move out to live in that male's harem (the sons have unrelated females coming to stay with them). By this point in the story, they're a far older species than humans and have reached dizzying technological feats. //END EDIT.

- Bipedal, digitigrade. Two thumbs on each hand, one on each side. No tails, because I know someone will ask. Obligate carnivores, eat meat, blood, and bones, and like us the healthiest thing for them to drink is water. More strongly eusocial than humans, who, according to a Google result I've found, are more "loosely eusocial," at least when compared to ants. These aliens aren't as intensely eusocial as ants, but definitely more than humans.
- Yes, I'm aware humans can be ambushers as well, these aliens are also adaptable but the ambush predation was what they primarily evolved from. Apex predators because of their intelligence like humans are, too, but before that, they were something like spotted hyenas on their world's food chain (without the scavenging), by that I mean they were powerful predators but still able to get killed by bigger, badder ones (spotties get mucked over by lions on the regular).
- Live on a tidally-locked planet with large oceans, 2 moons, under a red dwarf star, so I'm pretty sure there wasn't a day/night cycle so they can't have been nocturnal...saying this because of a different, slightly similar question that had an answer saying "Ambush predators fare better at night." Makes sense on Earth but (...probably) not here.
- They can see all the colors we do, with the added ability to see ultraviolet and infrared. No, I'm not changing this part.
- Family structure is kinda akin to a lion pride, one male has a bunch of female mates and they all raise the kids together. I should also tell you that females and males aren't actually all that sexually dimorphic, both are over 6 to a little bit over 7ft tall on average, the only differences between the sexes are akin to tigers with females being slightly smaller than males. A human would look at them and say they both look like huge beast-men (flat faces like ours though, no snouts) with hands the size of a human's head, and necks as thick as their own heads.

Comment: Lots of other stuff you'd need to clarify? Their local ecology/environment, omnivorous or purely carnivorous, their social structure on a larger scale - what happens to juvenile males in a family, do they form larger social groups/clans/tribe etc and their level of technology...

Comment: I feel the scope of the question is a bit large. Can you be more specific what exactly do you target when you ask about "society/culture"? Economy? Religion? Politics? Folklore? What?

Answer (score 5):

[Obligate carnivores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivore#Obligate_carnivores), you say, eh? Like in "lack the necessary physiology required to fully digest" plant matter.

Some consequences - *not necessary true but plausible* (so don't quibble too much over details)

1. their agriculture is mostly based on raising livestock - they can't be hunters and reach a high degree of civilization, they *need* to take the task of modifying their environment;
2. land ownership is looser than in human society, the "right of way" comes higher (denying access to a river is synonymous with "murder by starvation"). As such, one may extrapolate their sense of territory played a lower role during the history (think the mongol invasions - they were more interested in the projection of force and domination than in the land itself).
3. likely their religion is monotheistic - all 3 main monotheistic religions of Earth sprung from societies with in which herding animals were the main occupation (may have something to do with the image of "the good shepherd taking care of his livestock"). *Warning: may be a false track if their lifestock is way larger in size than them - see below*.
4. the population density is much lower than an "omnivorous civilization" - necessarily so, since the "food energetic efficiency" drops with every step on the way up (microbes → fungi → plants → livestock - top of chain as the main source of food) therefore the [carrying capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrying_capacity) of their habitat is lesser (I assume that carnivore isn't "infused" with "insectivore" meanings).
5. their "higher than humans degree of eusocial" is a bit of odds with their "obligate carnivore" physiology - the most sociable obligate carnivore species on Earth is the cat - [they can](https://icatcare.org/advice/the-social-structure-of-cat-life/) form [colonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feral_cat#Colonies) (if the food is in abundance) but are otherwise strongly territorial. The only explanation that can (long-term) force eusocial into the picture is if their prey/livestock is larger than them or there are dangers on the planet (including larger and/or more powerful predators) that the evolution selected community over the individual (if this is the case, they may be polytheistic).
6. being carnivores and limited by the carrying capacity of their habitat, their rate of birth is low and their childhood is long - good, that's how it needs to be for having intelligence as an evolutionary trait - "breeding like rabbits" is detrimental for selecting intelligence during evolution
7. since the sexual dimorphism is weak and the male sex is in minority - the bread-earner is the female and there's no "owner of the harem" status for the male (an intelligent group of females will overpower the male, were him to raise any supremacy challenges). Either the males are dumb (which can't be, due to the "they all raise the kids together" - which imply male participation) or they are the "thinker" (artist, scientist, teacher, orator, military strategist, etc) - if some fail to the "family" social duties, they'll end a-wandering in society (they will need serious social skills, tho, to make themselves liked enough to earn their bohemian existence)

Now that I think - more like a "feeling of guts" - the similarities with cat colonies are strong enough to suggest reading about them as a rich source of inspiration (if I'll have time to read about myself, I might add to this answer).

Comment: Edited my original post to be clearer, I hope.

Comment: @CAPichowsky My answer still stands in the conditions. Disagree with the "males stay in family" (too high demand for males in the society, "hoarding" males in a household is counterintuitive) and "males are the bosses of harems" (with little sexual dimorphism and the small "supply" of males in society as a source of power, there isn't enough in society to prevent/quell a "revolt" of females against a subordinate situation. If there is such a situation, it will only be for the space of few generations before it is overturned).

Comment: I never said there was a shortage of males, though? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @CAPichowsky from the "harem", indicates a disproportion between males and females.